OpenShift build error: couldn't find remote ref master
I have an OpenShift buildconfig that refers to a Git repository under bc.spec.source as follows:
git:
  uri: ssh://openshift@my-server/my-repo
  ref: master

When I clone the repository outside OpenShift with git clone ssh://openshift@my-server/my-repo, I end up in the default branch master. Yet when I start a build inside OpenShift, it runs into an error and oc logs lists the following details:
Adding cluster TLS certificate authority to trust store
Cloning "openshift@my-server/my-repo" ...
error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Why is the default branch master apparently invisible to OpenShift? How can I further diagnose and solve this problem?

Do you have access to the server my-server? Can you confirm in the logs that openshift is actually connecting to the appropriate service? Are there any errors in the logs on the server side? Are you certain that openshift has the necessary credentials to access my-server as user openshift?

@larsks Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can clearly discern e.g. by way of tcpdump on my-server and in my-server:/var/log/auth.log that OpenShift is connecting and has the necessary credentials: "Accepted key RSA SHA256:... found at ..."

Mystery solved now: I had not mentioned explicitly so far that the Git repository on my-server is also protected by access control lists (ACLs).
I had forgotten to set certain default ACLs (with setfacl -d). This led to a situation where files that were created by new activity in the Git repository bore too restrictive access rights. Hence OpenShift's Git client was not able to access certain branches.
After correcting all ACLs and default ACLs on my-server the build in OpenShift now works as expected.
